# Adding Dynamic Radio Buttons in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm working in Angular with just a plain old JS function that returns a list of data from an API.  I then turn the data into radio buttons like this:

```
function parseRoles(jsonObj) {
        console.log("passed: " + jsonObj);
        var tempRoleArray = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < jsonObj.role.length; i++) {
          tempRoleArray.push("<input type='radio' ng-model='user.role' value='" + jsonObj.role[i].role + "'>" + jsonObj.role[i].description + "&nbsp;");       
        }
        $("#userRoleEntry").html(tempRoleArray);
      }
```

Works great from the JS side but then the Angular side doesn't recognize "user.role" or "$scope.user.role" with "not defined" errors for each.  Is this because this input is a little different in the partial?  Something else?  Seems to be some questions alluding to Angular not really doing these kinds of things all that well...
EDIT: This is not the only input in the form.  The rest of them have been collected or returned from the API.  So not sure I can compile against scope and seems like kind of an overkill answer.  I could be wrong about that, of course.

Comment: you need to compile that element using  `$compile`,you could simply do `$compile($("#userRoleEntry"))($scope)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

woou, I would better change the API instead of adding `$compile` to your JS code!

The API should return the `jsonObj` and than you can easily build your View in Angular.

Also it is not the Angular-way to do something like this:

```
$("#userRoleEntry").html(tempRoleArray);
```

I assume that your JSON looks like this: An array with Objects.

```
$scope.roles = [{role: 'test', description: 'text'}]; // your "jsonObj.role"
```

Then your HTML should look like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="obj in roles">
  <input type="radio" ng-model="user.role" ng-value="obj.role"> {{obj.description}}
</div>
```

Comment: The API returns the JSON object in my original post as jsonObj.  And you are correct, that is the jQuery way of doing things, not the Angular way.

Comment: My way of saying, an improvement on this would be great!

Comment: Ok, one last trick question.  All of the checkboxes should be checked except the last.  Is there a way to handle that?

Comment: These are radio inputs so I am not sure if it's possible to check more than 1 ;)

Comment: Oh holy stupid holes I meant checkboxes...doesn't matter, I get the general gist.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to compile the DOM element in order to have angular pick it up.

See doc for examples: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile

As @pankajparkar points out, you can do `$compile($("#userRoleEntry"))($scope)` to compile your element.

Comment: Sorry, I see what you're getting at but I think you misunderstand my question.  Thank you though!